# Linked List infinite loop on first Node

Tags: java, list, loops, infinite

Printing the value of the node during the loop i discovered it infinite loops always on the first node when, for example, searching for a node which is not in the list(if its on the list it works). Im  using a node to point the first element as well as the last one.

This is my search method

```
public LNode search(int data){
    LNode currNode = head;
    while(data != currNode.value){
        if(currNode.next == null)
            return null;
        else{
            currNode = currNode.next;
            System.out.println("currnode " + currNode.value);
        }
    }
    return currNode;
}
```

the insert method which always inserts elements at the beginning

```
public void insert( LNode aNode ) { 
    if(head==null){
        head = aNode;
        tail = aNode;
        size++;
    }
    aNode.next = head;
    head = aNode;
    size++;
}
```

It is like the first entered element has a next node which is not set to null, but i dont know why it isnt null

Comment: LNode currNode = head; after this point if your head is null, you should skip the loop

Comment: @Striker that would throw an NPE at currNode.value causing the while-loop not to be executed anyways

Comment: I was re evaluating the code and the next node of the first entered element is the node itself, i dont know why.. i was thinking about 

if(currNode.next  == tail) , but it return NPE

Answer (score 2):

I think in

```
if(head==null){
    head = aNode;
    tail = aNode;
    size++;
}
```

is a return missing.
you make a loop with head and increase size by 2 with one insert.

Comment: Oh, right, didnt notice that, added an else statement and now it works, thank you